# ASP.NET 5 Publish to Azure Gulp libass error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, gulp-sass

I have an asp.net 5 website (using gulp and gulp-sass) I'm working on but whenever I try to publish to my Azure website I get the following error

`DNU(0,0): Error : The`libsass`binding was not found in project_path\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-11\binding.node` *Full stack trace below*

I had this exact same error in the Visual Studio Task Running Explorer until I followed [this article](http://blog.boro2g.co.uk/grunt-and-gulp-tasks-in-visual-studio-2015-libsass-error/), but I'm still getting the error when I publish.

Any help?

```
DNU(0,0): Error : The `libsass` binding was not found in project_path\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-11\binding.node
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error : This usually happens because your node version has changed.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error : Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current node version.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at Object.sass.getBinaryPath (project_path\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:158:11)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at Object.<anonymous>
    (project_path\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:16:36)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at require (module.js:380:17)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at Object.<anonymous>
    (project_path\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:183:21)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error :     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): Error : The 'prepublish' script failed with status code 8.
```

Comment: what node version do you use locally?

Comment: Make sure you have the same version of node locally and on your Website. You should be able to use Kudu's debug console ({sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole) to navigate to your project_path/node_modules folder and manually install libsass to confirm that this is the issue.

Comment: Node version locally is v4.2.4 - npm is 2.14.12

Comment: The website is running v4.2.3 from the looks of it. I cant find any node_modules directory in the Kudu debug console though. I downgraded to node v4.2.3 and ran npm rebuild and everything still works fine locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused because **the version of node Visual Studio 2015 is using in the prepublish script is different to the one you are using for development tasks**.

You can test this by putting `node --version` in your prepublish script inside project.json.

Mine outputs `v0.10.31`.

**You can change the version used by most of the Visual Studio tooling** (Task Runner Explorer, node package restore, etc.) in Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->External Web Tools by moving `$(PATH)` to the top or adding `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to the top.

Unfortunately, **this is not respected in the prepublish script**.

A workaround is to place all your prepublish tasks in script and then call that.

project.json :

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": ["prepublish"]
  }
...
```

prepublish.cmd :

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\nodejs;.\node_modules\.bin;%PATH%

call npm install || goto :error
call bower install || goto :error
call gulp clean || goto :error
call gulp min || goto :error
goto :EOF

:error
echo Failed with error #%errorlevel%.
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/101) is a GitHub issue tracking the request to update node and npm within VS.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the node_modules folders in your local repo, and restarting VS.
That solved my problem.

Explanation here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/782